# A Clockwork Scrooge

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

After a night of traveling through time with the three spirits, Ebenezer Scrooge was brought back to his house. The spirits left him with this message:

"For *some, values opposite* that of society are too far ingrained to correct. However you, Scrooge, have the opportunity to change for the better."

As they departed, Ebenezer noticed that the hour markers on his clock were all jumbled up. What did Scrooge do that morning after contemplating the spirits’ guidance?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That morning, Scrooge

> **REPENT**(ed). Each of the twelve boxes corresponds to a number between 1 and twelve ("the hour markers on his clock were all jumbled up"). In clockwise order starting from the top, they are:
>
>  `11, 1, 6, 3, 9, 12, 7, 4, 10, 2, 5, 8` [(diagram)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sMMV.png)
>
>  The text hints that we have to add the numbers opposite from one another ("For *some, values opposite* that of society" = "sum values opposite"). Thus, we get (starting with 11+7):
>
>  `18, 5, 16, 5, 14, 20`
>
>  Converting these numbers to letters (A=1, B=2, etc.), we get **REPENT**.